# Select query from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables customers,campaigns,deals and facts2 .I wrote a query like below to display like

```
SELECT id,
(select customer.name from customer where customer.id = facts2.customer_id) 
  AS Customername,
(select campaign.name from campaign where campaign.id = facts2.campaign_id) 
  AS Campaignname,
(select deal.name from jb_deal where deal.id = facts2.deal_id) 
  AS Dealname,
revenue 
from facts2;
```

```
    +--------------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
    | Customername | Campaignanme |  Dealname         |  revenue |
    +-------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
    |           A |       Camp1 |               Deal1 |   100  |
    |           A |       Camp1 |               Deal2 |   200  | 
    |           A |       Camp2 |               Deal3 |   300  |
    |           B |       CampB |              DealB1 |   100  |
    |           B |       CampB |              DealB2 |   200  |
    |           C |       CampC |               Deal3 |   300  |
    +-------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

I want to display sql table without repeating customer names and campaign names as shown below.

```
    +--------------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
    | customername | campaignanme | dealname         |  Revenue |
    +-------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
    |           A |       Camp1 |               Deal1 |   100  |
    |             |             |               Deal2 |   200  | 
    |             |       Camp2 |               Deal3 |   300  |
    |           B |       CampB |              DealB1 |   100  |
    |             |             |              DealB2 |   200  |
    |           C |       CampC |               Deal3 |   300  |
    +-------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think it's more a presentation issue, not database.

Comment: `join = cartesian product`, you can try union instead

Answer (score 0):

You Wont Be able to make it like this still you can use UNION to Take distinct entries.
If you want you can get like this

```
SELECT `result`.`Customername`,`result`.`Campaignname`,
GROUP_CONCAT(`result`.`Dealname`) AS `Dealname`,SUM(`revenue`) AS `revenue` FROM (SELECT id,
(select customer.name from customer where customer.id = facts2.customer_id) 
  AS Customername,
(select campaign.name from campaign where campaign.id = facts2.campaign_id) 
  AS Campaignname,
(select deal.name from jb_deal where deal.id = facts2.deal_id) 
  AS Dealname,
revenue 
from facts2) AS `result` GROUP BY `result`.`Campaignname`,`result`.`Customername`;
```

the result will be some what like this

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
| Customername | Campaignanme |  Dealname        |  revenue |
+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
|           A |       Camp1 |         Deal1,Deal2 |   300  |
|           A |       Camp2 |               Deal3 |   300  |
|           B |       CampB |       DealB1,DealB2 |   300  |
|           C |       CampC |               Deal3 |   300  |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
```